# Browser Back Button Issue in Website with Frames

Tags: html

My website has 5 frames where 4 remains static except center frame.

1: Header
2: Left Column
3: Main Content
4: Right Column
5: Footer.

My main logic goes in MAIN content frame. Thus, when page gets reloaded, it reloads only MAIN content and not entire page.

However, issue is now that, when user makes 3 to 4 request on MAIN Content frame ( Select, Review, Order, Shipping etc) and clicks on Browser Back button, it takes him to HOME page.

This is really irritating and users are not liking.

May I know how can I fix so that when users clicks on browser back button, it reloads previous frame and not the previous page?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, frames. I haven't come across those in, well... over a decade now :S

Comment: You're discovering one of the reasons why frames are deprecated. Do you have to use frames? Is there no way you can modify your website to not use frames?

Comment: @Dai So much this...at least 8 years since i saw this the last time...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  like `parent.frames[2].history.forward()` each time..

The useful code can be found here http://www.webreference.com/js/column36/navigating.html